# switch with character, how to convert character to work with switch ?

Tags: java

when i try to print out the result with switch i can't get any result 
so i thought to convert char to integer so the switch statement gona work but isn't so any ideas about how to find solution

```
echar guestGuess = input.next().charAt(0);
int x = (int)guestGuess;
switch(x){
    case '1':   
System.out.println(answer.isfirstGuessRight(guestGuess) + "\n");
break;
        case '2:
'System.out.println("We are kontrol your answer" + answer.issecandGuessRight(guestGuess));
```

Comment: What is echar in java? Also, check your `case '2`!

Comment: Use a debugger to find out what is happend. Why you do not use `input.nextInt()`?

Comment: What is echar? a new datatype?

Comment: I think i got your problem. I think when you press 1 as input it will be taken as character and according to the actual value you want to execute its case! so you should use`int x= (int)guestGuess - 48` subtracting the value of `0` in `ASCII` to get the actual input you want to have.

Answer (score 1):

There's not problem in Java to use char for switch.
You don't have to cast to int for that.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter something, and I'll take the first char only");
    char c = scan.next().trim().charAt(0);

    switch (c) {
        case '1':
            System.out.println("1 for sure");
            break;
        case '2':
            System.out.println("I think it's 2");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("I don't know");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this one but its not working i can't get any output. its like the compiler doesn't go in the switch statement

Comment: That's curious. What System.out.println((int)c); gives you?